# Why does the type of Seq.concat involve a flexible type?

Tags: f#, flexible-type

I define two functions, one with and one without a flexible type:

```
let concatA = Seq.concat // ... : seq<#seq<'b>> -> seq<'b>
let concatB = concatA : seq<seq<'b> -> seq<'b>
```

Is there a context in which I can use one but not the other?

My understanding is that flexible types are helpful for functions `f: #B -> #B`, where the type guarantees that `(f (x : D)) : D` for any `D` derived from `B`. I don't see how the flexible type is helpful for `Seq.concat`?

(I chose `Seq.concat` as an example because its used in the [documentation for Flexible Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233198.aspx) uses it, but using `concatB` in that example still seems to type everything.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It lets you call `Seq.concat` with a sequence of specific collections. For example:

```
[ [1]; [2] ] |> concatA  // Works
[ [1]; [2] ] |> concatB  // Does not work
```

The argument is `list<list<int>>` which only implements the interface `seq<list<int>>`. This means that the second call does not work (because the argument requires `seq<seq<int>>`), but the first one does thanks to the flexible type - `seq<#seq<int>>` unifies with `seq<list<int>>`.

A slightly confusing thing is that if F# knows the required type of a collection literal, it sometimes inserts conversions behind the scenes, so the following would actually work too (but only thanks to a hidden conversion):

```
concatB [ [1]; [2] ]
```

Comment: It's maybe worth noting that in C# that would have worked..    

F# generic types do not support covariance or contravariance according to https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf  

In C# a `List<List<T>>` is a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` as `IEnumerable<out T>` is covariant.  

C# interactive:  
> IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> x = new List<List<int>>();
> x
List<List<int>>(0) { }

Comment: I assume that flexible types were "invented" to bring something similar to covariance to classes or the application side of generic types? Opting into "subtype of myT" (=covariance) whenever i need it in my generic type composition.